# Editing images error message

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to edit a picture through edit picture page and I get this error messages:

---

A PHP Error was encountered

```
Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/editslideshows.php

Line Number: 86

Backtrace:

File: C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\companygiondaci\application\views\editslideshows.php
Line: 86
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\companygiondaci\application\controllers\Cuploadfile.php
Line: 81
Function: view

File: C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\companygiondaci\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once


A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: image

Filename: views/editslideshows.php

Line Number: 94

Backtrace:

File: C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\companygiondaci\application\views\editslideshows.php
Line: 94
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\companygiondaci\application\controllers\Cuploadfile.php
Line: 81
Function: view

File: C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\companygiondaci\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: views/editslideshows.php

Line Number: 94

Backtrace:

File: C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\companygiondaci\application\views\editslideshows.php
Line: 94
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\companygiondaci\application\controllers\Cuploadfile.php
Line: 81
Function: view

File: C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\companygiondaci\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
------------------------------

views\editslideshows.php


Line 86:  <?php foreach ($images as $image): ?>

Line 94:  <?php echo $image->slideshow_image; ?>
```

---

Also, after I press "Upload File" it adds more picture instead of editing or replacing the old one which I expected.

I wonder why?

---

controllers/Cuploadfile.php

```
function uploadedit()
{
    //set preferences
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|gif';
    $config['max_size']    = '500000';

    //load upload class library
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->load->model('Mpages');


    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('filename'))
    {
        // case - failure
        $upload_error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('addslideshows', $upload_error);
    }
    else
    {
        // case - success
        $upload_data = $this->upload->data();           
        $filename = $upload_data['file_name'];
        $image_id = $this->uri->segment(3);

        $data['images'] = $this->Mpages->edit_slideshow($filename, $image_id);

        $data['success_msg'] = '<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Your file <strong>' . $upload_data['file_name'] . '</strong> was successfully uploaded!</div>';
        $this->load->view('editslideshows', $data);
    }
}
```

views/editslideshows.php

```
    <?php foreach ($images as $image): ?>

    <img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/'.$image->slideshow_image); ?>" height="150" width="300">

    <?php endforeach; ?>    

    <br><br>

    <?php echo $image->slideshow_image; ?>
```

Models/Mpages.php

```
public function edit_slideshow($filename, $image_id)
{   

    $this->db->set('slideshow_image', $filename);
    $this->db->where('image_id', $image_id);
    return $this->db->update('slideshow');

}
```

Comment: Var dump your `$data['images']` variable. Looks like its not returning anything

Comment: When I click "EDIT" this error message appears: The connection was reset

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.